# Need a Macro to run on a specific sheet not the Active one

Tags: vba, excel

I have This Macro and it needs to run on the sheet "Customer List", instead of the active sheet. This is a part of a series of macros so i cant just click onto sheet. Thanks.

```
Sub Check()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("D2:D100")
    dat = rng
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
            rng(i, -2).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code below:

```
Sub Check()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Sheets("Customer List").Range("D2:D100")
    dat = rng.Value
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
            rng(i, -2).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```